# After upgrading to 11.04, there's no icons, no menus, nothing

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I've just upgraded from 10.04 -> 10.10 -> 11.04 and after the reboot, I'm presented with my desktop wallpaper, a mouse cursor.... and that's it!

I was able to get to firefox, but only by hitting the power button, clicking Help, and then selecting "Get help online".

<kbd>Alt-F2</kbd> doesn't show the run dialog, so I'm unable to get to a terminal or anything!

Any ideas or help?

---

*update* : I was able to boot in recovery mode and started the root terminal with network access. `apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop && apt-get ubuntu-desktop` did not change anything

Comment: Select 'Ubuntu Classic (No effects)' at the login screen, that should get you to the desktop.

Comment: try to reinstall ubuntu desktop with `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @mikewhatever, there's no login screen - it automatically takes me to the desktop.

Comment: @Alvar, I can't get to the terminal..!

Comment: @nickf yes you can, enter in recovery console, then you should get to a prompt. you should always have a command for opening a terminal! 
I have F4.

Comment: `Alt-Ctrl-T` opened the terminal for me in the end.

Comment: cool, did my suggestion work? :)

Comment: @Alvar, I'm not sure! Initially not, but I tried a heap of things, including doing that again. Running `gnome-panel` got the header panel back again, which helped. From there I was able to get to the config and turn off the auto-login, and then I was able to choose a different desktop from the login screen. I'm currently running on Unity now, and it's fine. Thanks for the help.